# Diagonal difference

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, python-2.x

Given

> You are given a square matrix of size \$N×N\$. Calculate the absolute difference of the sums across the two main diagonals.

Input Format

> The first line contains a single integer N. The next N lines contain N integers (each) describing the matrix.

Constraints

> \$1\leq N \leq 100\$
>
> \$−100 \leq A_{i} \leq 100\$

Solution

```
def diagonal_difference(matrix):
    l = sum(matrix[i][i] for i in range(N))
    r = sum(matrix[i][N-i-1] for i in range(N))
    return abs(l - r)

matrix = []
N = input()
for _ in range(N):
    matrix.append(map(int, raw_input().split()))

print diagonal_difference(matrix)
```

Is there more elegant solution for the given problem. Also, I am getting intuition that I can use `reduce`, is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of indexing to access the rows, you could use iteration:

```
l = sum(row[i] for i, row in enumerate(matrix))
```

Instead of doing two passes over `matrix` to calculate `l` and `r`, you could accumulate the difference in one pass: (note also negative indexing from end of list)

```
difference = sum(row[i] - row[-i-1] for i, row in enumerate(matrix))
return abs(difference)
```

The single-pass approach would also allow you to process input line by line, instead of storing the whole matrix in memory.

Answer (score 3):

My big concern with this approach is that you store the entire matrix before doing any processing. Since the size of the matrix is \$O(N^2)\$, you could run into occupancy problems for large \$N\$.

A simpler approach would be to get the contribution to the difference with each row of the matrix, as you read it. You're only ever storing a single row at once.

That is:

```
N = int(raw_input())
difference = 0
for i in xrange(N):
    row = raw_input().split()
    difference += (int(row[i]) - int(row[N-1-i]))
print abs(difference)
```

A few other items of note here:

- I'm getting `N` via a `raw_input()` call, not `input()`. In general you should be wary of using `input()` and evaluating arbitrary code from the user.

  (Although that advice only applies to Python 2; in Python 3 the names have changed.)
- In Python 2, using `xrange()` is preferable to `range()` because it doesn't create a list for the entire range.
- I'm being lazy about the coercion to `int()`, and reducing from \$N^2\$ calls to \$2N\$ calls.

Comment: I usually like to think in terms of `pure functions` which takes some input and returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass `N` to `diagonal_difference`, that's bad practice. You should either be passing it as a parameter, or at least determining it within the function since it's just `len(matrix)`. Also `N` isn't a good name, just because the question used that doesn't mean you need to. Code has different requirements than a brief. Maybe `matrix_size` or some other explicit name.

It's also odd to have `raw_input()` when you're actually expecting input. Putting at least `">"` is recommended so that the user can see that the script is waiting for input, not just running code silently.

Comment: I think you are advocating `pure functions` regarding `N`. Seems good to me.

Comment: `input` should be avoided by @alexwlchan

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/a/4915408/4260745